# Xubuntu 14.04 ATI/AMD driver problem

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, xubuntu, radeon

I'm trying to install a driver for ATI Radeon HD 7900 series.
I've read a lot of different articles, but I still cannot to do it.

For example, I've tryed almost all instructions/way from this page
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

There is always only one result, after reboot Xubuntu can't start. It shows only loading screen, and I can't even open terminal by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>!
I guess, I may to boot from LiveCD and look at starting logs.. But I don't know where starting logs are.

Answer (score 0):

The most up to date instructions for installing the binary driver can be found on [this unofficial wiki page](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Utopic_Installation_Guide).

If you don't intend to play games, I would advice you to stay with the open source driver (*radeon*) which will give you **the most performance in 2D**.

For more help, please attach the result of `/var/log/messages` and the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.1.log`. You can use the command `cat /path/to/log | pastebinit` to upload your errors logs on the web and easiliy provide the error messages.

Note also, that there was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1479913) with the latest fglrx driver. A fix has been released, be sure to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` your install.

Comment: Thanks for answer, aklmie. I've solved my issue.

I've got an integrated graphics in my i5 and I just turned it off in BIOS and then my Xubuntu was loaded successfully with fglrx driver :D